# NoMethodError (undefined method `last' for true:TrueClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, nomethoderror

I got `` NoMethodError (undefined method `last' for true:TrueClass): ``
from `` app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:71:in `uploads' ``

Here is the script

```
  def uploads 
    @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find(params[:id])
    a = @post.images.attach(params[:file])
    render json: {url: url_for(a.last)}
  end
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong. Any advice?

Comment: It seems like the method `attach` is returning true after the successful operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the 'attach' method is returning 'true' or 'false' as to whether it was successful or not rather than assigning the file to the variable.

Personally I'd remove the variable 'a', then just use:

```
url_for(@post.images.last)
```